# Laravel Eloquent return value depending on the value of a relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to return the data from a table based on a column's value. Let me explain.

I have 3 tables. `books`, `genres` and a pivot table to associate the values of these 2 tables.

***Tables***

1. `books`
2. `genres`
3. `book_genre`

There is a `many-to-many` relationship, since a `book` can contain different `genres` and a `genre` can be associated with different `books`.

***Relations***

`Book Model`

```
class Book extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'language',
        'thumbnail',
        'active'
    ];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new ExcludeBookWhenInactiveRelations());
    }

    /**
     * Genders relationship
     *
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function genres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class);
    }
}
```

`Genre Model`

```
class Genre extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'active'
    ];

    /**
     * Books relationship
     *
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to create a `global scope` in my `Book` model so when queried, it only returns `books` whose `genres` have not been disabled. That is, if in my `genre` table, I change the `active` property of a `genre` to false and that `genre` was associated with a `book`, then it should not show me that `book`.

Here is the `Global Scope` that I am creating:

```
class ExcludeBookWhenInactiveRelations implements Scope
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param Model $model
     * @return Builder|void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        return $builder->whereHas('genres', function ($query) {
            return $query->where('active', true);
        });
    }
}
```

What happens is that when I change the value of the `active` property of a `genre` to `false`, it is not shown the `genere` in the collection, but if that `book` had 2 `genres`, and one of them keeps the `active` property in `true`, then it follows me returning the `book`, and what I'm trying to do is if the `book` has at least 1 `gender` disabled `(false)`, then it doesn't show it in the collection.

Could you help me with my problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: truly interesting question.

Comment: we are dealing with this query here. "select * from `books` where exists (select * from `genres` inner join `book_genre` on `genres`.`id` = `book_genre`.`genre_id` where `books`.`id` = `book_genre`.`book_id` and `active` = 1)"

Comment: and we want this "select * from `books` where not exists (select * from `genres` inner join `book_genre` on `genres`.`id` = `book_genre`.`genre_id` where `books`.`id` = `book_genre`.`book_id` and `active` = 0)
"

Comment: @r89human Thanks for putting me in the right direction. You were right. The query you showed me was the query I needed. I have converted it to Eloquent and now I get the expected result. Please create an answer to mark it as correct. Again thank you very much.

Comment: thanks. please edit my answer and put your eloquent query there.

Comment: can you please share your eloquent query?

Comment: @r89human I can't edit your answer. I have posted the solution below my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your eloquent settings were creating this query.

```
select * from books where exists (select * from genres inner join book_genre on genres.id = book_genre.genre_id where books.id = book_genre.book_id and active = 1)
```

here if book had only one active genre it would be selected. which was wrong. now you needed another query which is not very different.

```
select * from books where not exists (select * from genres inner join book_genre on genres.id = book_genre.genre_id where books.id = book_genre.book_id and active = 0)
```

here if book has only one not active genre it would be unselected from final record.

@leo95batista provided this query in eloquent.

```
class ExcludeBookWhenInactiveRelation implements Scope
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param Model $model
     * @return Builder|void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        return $builder->whereDoesntHave('genres', function (Builder $query) {
            return $query->where('active', false);
        });
    }
}
```